# Can we have more than one image gallery using Apple's PhotoScroller example?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I've implemented Apple's PhotoScroller (for ARC) code, wonderfully modified by Steph Sharp (https://github.com/stephsharp/PhotoScroller) to show one scrollable image gallery in my project.

Now when I replicate the same for another image gallery I am stuck at the first image itself. Can anybody suggest how to have more than one image gallery using Apple's PhotoScroller example?

Comment: I just tested my PhotoScroller code by creating 2 image galleries in different tabs, and it seemed to work fine. Are you able to post some code where you think the problem is?

Comment: Hi Steph!!! 
The pinch zoom feature is not working on ipad retina. What could be the reason?